# no CUDA-capable device is detected inside LXC container

Tags: linux, cuda, container, lxc

I followed [the following instructions](http://sqream.com/setting-cuda-linux-containers-2/) and read the official guide in detail in order to set up Cuda inside an LXC container.

When I try to execute the sample ./deviceQuery script from the official sample codes **I get a PASS in the host**. However when I execute the script **in the container I get the following error**:

```
$ ./deviceQuery 
./deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

cudaGetDeviceCount returned 38
-> no CUDA-capable device is detected
Result = FAIL
```

Cuda is recognised and installed **inside the container**:

```
$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2015 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Aug_11_14:27:32_CDT_2015
Cuda compilation tools, release 7.5, V7.5.17
```

The nVidia devices are mounted **inside the host and the LXC container**:

```
$ ls -l /dev/nvidia*
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 195,   0 Dec 20 23:31 /dev/nvidia0
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 195, 255 Dec 20 23:31 /dev/nvidiactl
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 246,   0 Dec 20 23:31 /dev/nvidia-uvm
```

When I run `sudo nvidia-smi` **inside the container** I get the following error:

```
Failed to initialize NVML: Unknown Error
```

How can I make the device available inside the container?

linux/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I had this very same issue, which I wrote about at length [here](https://bradford.la/2016/GPU-FFMPEG-in-LXC).

The issue you are having may be caused by using an LXC template that doesn't match your host. I am using Proxmox 4.4, which is based on Debian 8.6. My container was based on Ubuntu 16.04. Just like you, I saw the passed nodes in the container with **root** as the owner and group, not **nobody:nogroup** as expected.

A [forum post I stumbled on](https://forum.openvz.org/index.php?t=tree&goto=52646&S=8435426c35e817f11e7afea78c459581#msg_52646) inspired me to build a new container based on a template that matched my host, Debian 8.6. Once I did that the `/dev` nodes were owned by `nobody:nogroup` and `nvidia-smi` correctly identified my GPU.

If yours don't match, I strongly recommend you try making them match - the only way I am aware of is to rebuild it.